# Is there a term for the string in an email address before the @ character?

Tags: email, terminology

When describing a URL, there are well-defined terms for each part of the URL, like protocol, hostname, path and query.

When describing an email address, the part after the @ character is the domain. Is there a universally accepted term for the part before the @ character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd generally refer to it as the mailbox, or the username. I'm not aware of a single canonical descriptor that is used in daily language, but I don't talk about the parts of email addresses much.

Probably the most correct formal name for it is the "local-part", as referenced in the rfc:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.11

Answer (score 0):

I've also heard the term "stem" used, but might be confusing that with some other terminology.